# Spring boot not scanning any sub packages and also the class files under same package

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, spring-restcontroller, white-labelling

After i write a simple route using rest controller and spring boot the routes always return 404 whether
If the route is mention in a separate package or in same package.
The route only works if the route is defined in the main function where @SpringBootApplication is mentioned please help me
package com.gowtham;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gowtham")
public class DemoApplication {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RestController
    public class controller {
        @GetMapping("/greet")
        public String hello() {
            return "HELLO";
        }
    }
```

The /greet route works

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ccc {
    
    @GetMapping("/gg")
    public String hello() {
        return "HELLO";
        }
    }
```

But this route /gg which is inside .controller package which is under the main package doesn't work i tried moving the class "ccc" inside the main package and i also tried to scan base packages but no use

if i import the same program in other computers it is running fine

**Package Structure**

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two `ccc.java` files in two different packages? Also, try posting your code directly in the question, not in separate pictures.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you go to the folder directly inside the file explorer and check if the structure of the project is correct. i.e. The main class is at the root and all other sub packages are correctly under the root folder. Sometime while creating package folder are create with the package name itself and are not proper structured.

Comment: yes it is structured right infact if i send the project to someone and if they import it it will run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also facing the same issue as mentioned above. I tried using Spring Boot version 2.7.9 instead of 3.0.3. It worked fine, although not sure what changed in the new version.

Comment: This issue is discussed and resolved here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610220/spring-boot-endpoint-controller-not-found-404

Comment: Ok I'll try that now

Comment: I just changed the version now it's working thanks man

Comment: Alternate Solution: This issue happens when the application's path contains a space. I removed all spaces in my application path and restarted the app, the issue got resolved. I'm running on Windows 10 and I'm not sure if this issue happens on MacOS also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Spring Boot application is scanning the correct packages for your controllers. You can specify the base package for component scanning by adding the @ComponentScan annotation to your main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gowtham")
public class DemoApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried component scan  but still same error