# Spring-Boot Endpoint/Controller Not Found 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

When I create a new spring-boot project and then add a simple controller and try to hit the endpoint, I get 404 (Not found). If I move the same code to the main spring boot application it works (I've added the annotations @RestController.. as you can see)
The other strange thing is that if I get the "not working code" from another machine (create the project on another PC and clone/transfer it to my current machine), it works completely fine.
What may be the issue?
Current machine(Mac Air M1)
Spring-Boot -v 3.0.3
Gradle 8.0.1
Installed using brew

I tried other things from different sources. Nothing helped for now.

[Main App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PTfS.png)
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nro5d.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your application configuration seems like? Did you add context? If yes, please call with context name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade/upgrade your spring to a different version, 3.0.3 has a bug with component scanning
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34379

Comment: I created a new project with a downgraded version of spring and it worked fine. Much thanks!